# Reference in VBA conditional format formula is not working

Tags: excel, vba

This is a snippet of a much larger code.  I have the following code that I am trying to use to insert a conditional format in a range of cells where the active column can change. I would like the conditional format formula to update as the active column changes. `f1 = "=IF(AND(MID(CTO_1,6,1)=""W"",NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-7]))),RC12<>RC19,RC11<>RC19)"`'this works correctly, but when I try to modify it to be dynamic it doesn't work.

I have spent a many hours searching for a solution with no luck

```
Private Sub test()

Worksheets("C9 map").Activate

Dim lstCol, lstRow, nCol As Integer
Dim cRng3, cRng2, cRng1, strRow As Variant

lstCol = LastRowColumn("c") ' function to find last column
lstRow = LastRowColumn("r") ' function to find last row

nCol = lstCol + 1

strRow = 5

Range(Columns(nCol).Rows(strRow), Columns(nCol).Rows(strRow)).Activate

Dim actCol, hdrRow5 As Variant

actCol = ActiveCell.Column

Dim f1 As String

hdrRow5 = 5
cRng1 = "RC" & 11 'Column K = 11
cRng2 = "RC" & 12 'Column L = 12
cRng3 = "RC" & ActiveCell.Column

f1 = "=IF(AND(MID(CTO_1,6,1)=""W"",NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-7]))),cRng2<>cRng3,cRng1<>cRng3)"

With Columns(actCol)
    .ColumnWidth = 20
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
End With
With Range(Columns(actCol).Rows(hdrRow5), Columns(actCol).Rows(lstRow))
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=f1


        With .FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = False
            .Color = -16776961
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that your cRng1, cRng2 and cRng3 are given as string in your code, because of the **""**.

Change your line to:

```
f1 = "=IF(AND(MID(CTO_1,6,1)=""W"",NOT(ISBLANK(RC[-7])))," & cRng2 & "<>" & cRng3 & "," & cRng1 & "<>" & cRng3 & ")"
```

Comment: Worked great.  I knew I was missing something simple. I truly appreciate the help.